Async database connection as FastAPI Router dependency
I'm trying to initialize a ConnectionPool using asyncpg and then I'm using this pool to create a connection each time I need to read something from my DB. It was working fine until I moved my SQL endpoints to an APIRouter. I'm a bit lost now since I couldn't find docs for this specific case.
To create the connection, I'm using the app's lifecycle on main.py:
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
   app.state.db_pool = await create_async_pool()
   yield
   await app.state.db_pool.close()

Then I'm declaring two dependencies in main.py:
async def get_database():
   yield app.state.db_pool

async def get_db_connection(pool: asyncpg.pool.Pool = Depends(get_database)):
   async with pool.acquire() as connection:
      yield connection

Up until here, everything works perfectly fine and I can use my database on my app's endpoints written on main.py. Now I want to migrate these endpoints to a new API router on a file called analytics.py. Importing these dependencies directly from my analytics.py returns circular imports errors, but I'm completely unable to pass on the latest dependency into my new Analytics router. My file tree currently looks like this:
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── analytics
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── analytics.py

Any idea how I could fix this? There must definitely be something that I'm missing
My complete files look like this, main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
   app.state.db_pool = await create_async_pool()
   yield
   await app.state.db_pool.close()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

app.include_router(analytics.router)

async def get_database():
   yield app.state.db_pool

async def get_db_connection(pool: asyncpg.pool.Pool = Depends(get_database)):
   async with pool.acquire() as connection:
      yield connection

@app.get("/"):
async def hello():
   return {"message": "Hello world!"}

analytics.py:
from fastapi import APIRouter
from app.main import get_db_connection

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/analytics"
)

@router.post("/test")
async def test_analytics(input_data, db = Depends(get_db_connection)):
    return "OK"

The error with this configuration is:
Import Error: cannot import name 'get_db_connection' from partially initialized module 'app.main' (most likely due to a circular import)


I answered a similar question a while ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78596305/21152416. Guess, it could be helpful for you as well!

add the code of your modules. At least their import sections. Also, add the error traceback

hey @YuriiMotov, I updated my answer to include the code and the traceback, thank you!

We don't see the full code of your main and analytics modules. So, it's hard to say for sure why you have this circular imports errors.
But moving these two dependencies into separate file (e.g. dependencies.py) should help you.
Also, modify lifespant to:
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
   db_pool = await create_async_pool()
   yield {"db_pool": db_pool}
   await db_pool.close()

And use request.state instead of app.state in get_database:

from fastapi import Request

async def get_database(request: Request):
   yield request.state.db_pool


The analytics.py file contains just a basic FastAPI API router with some endpoints that receive the mentioned database connection as its dependency. Moving both functions to a separate file start giving errors about not finding app.state

Use request.state instead of app.state. I updated the answer

moving the dependencies to a separate file does not do the trick. When using request.state, it returns an error: Attribute error: 'state' object has no attribute 'db_pool'. I edited my answer to include the rest of the code

I forgot one more thing - you should yield the dictionary with db_pool from lifespan instead of setting the attribute of app.state.
Modified the answer

Thank you Yurii, this works! However, it just came to my mind, is it possible or better to just declare the dependency on the lifespan of the API router instead of on the lifespan of the app? I don't really need the database dependency anywhere else

I think it doesn't matter. You can move it to router's lifespan. But leave the DB dependency functions in a separate file. BTW, is it fair that the total number of votes is "-1" for the answer that works?

I don't think it's fair, no. I marked it as the correct answer though, hope someone removes his/her downvote
